# Nuxt 3 Runtime config values are not replaced by env variables

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

I'm using **Nuxt 3**

i have **.env** like this

```
NUXT_CAPTCHA_KEY=123456
```

and this is **nuxt.config.ts**

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      captchaKey: 'some value',
    }
  },
});
```

and in my component **login.vue**

I want to use **Recaptcha** like this

```
function login() {
  const config = useRuntimeConfig()
  console.log('config', config.public.captchaKey);
}
```

I think it must print `'123456'` in console

as it said in [document](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/going-further/runtime-config/)

but it doesn't.

and it prints `'some value'`

why is that ?

Comment: @Mises empty string is just fallback value

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76960199/how-to-update-env-variable-on-build-time-in-nuxt-3

Guys can you please help me on this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`captchaKey` is public so the .env key must be named `NUXT_PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY`